# Bars or Boxplot

Tags: r

For my thesis work I need to plot data as dry mass content, Brix, sugar content,   etc., of 12 genotypes of onions. My question is, what is convenient to use,  barplots or boxplots? Personally I like boxplots more because I see the distribution but I do not want to misuse this.

Here are two examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The plots are misleading because the y-axis does not have the same scale (ylim=c(0,20). I would use Boxplots.

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.6549/abstract. It depends on what you want to show. You could also consider a stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 2):

Boxplots are highly preferable in general. If you have few enough individual data points, you might even consider superimposing them on the boxplots. (You do need to consider appropriate limits for the y-axis in any case. One might argue that your second example, with y-axis starting at 9, overemphasizes the differences among genotypes.)

[Edward Tufte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte), a renowned expert on display of information, recommends maximizing the data/ink ratio. If a plot has a lot of ink that can be removed without losing information about the data, then the data/ink ratio is too low. Barplots almost always have a very low data/ink ratio.

See [Tufte's website](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/index) for further information and discussion.